# Event.context not present on migrating from 0.7 to 0.9.2 [Ractive]

Tags: javascript, ractivejs

I have a **query** regarding the migration of Ractive from 0.7 to 0.9.2:

**Template:**

```
{{#if degrees }}
<a class="degree-matcher__degree-link" on-click="selectDegree" href="#">
   {{ title }}
</a>
{{/if degrees}}
```

**JS:**

```
this.view.on('selectDegree', event => {
   event.original.preventDefault()
   this.updateUrl(event.context.id)
})
```

**event.context** is no longer present, so what's the best way to resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

ok so have fixed it using the `get` functionality.

```
 this.view.on('selectDegree', event => {
  event.original.preventDefault()
  this.updateUrl(event.get('id'))
})
```

If anyone has any better answer, looking forward to it!